# Placing Keynote 6.0 elements into Illustrator CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, mac

I upgraded to OS 10.9 and Keynote 6.0. In the previous version of Keynote, I was able to easily paste charts into Illustrator CS5 as vector objects, of which the elements could be independently manipulated by releasing the clipping mask.

However, with Keynote 6.0, the same charts paste into Illustrator as `.tiff` files. Text alone pastes fine, but if I try to paste text *and* a Keynote shape, for example, the two elements are placed into Illustrator as one `.tiff` file. I am unable to open a Keynote slide from within Illustrator, so I don't know what would happen in that case.

Is there a way to force a vector object placement in Illustrator? Or is this a Keynote-side copying issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like pasting objects as vector objects is among the deleted features in Keynote 6.0, as others have [noticed](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23607259#23607259).

If you haven't opened your slides in Keynote 6.0 yet, just open my presentation in Keynote 5.3, which fortunately is still stored post-update in `~/Applications/iWork '09/`. This should work like it used to.

However, if you *did* open your slides in Keynote 6.0 already, the new filetype (that you agreed to convert to when you opened the presentation) is not backwards compatible and you'll probably have to restore the presentation from before you opened it or "export to iWork '09".

Huge pain.

Answer (score 1):

Not as convenient, but Keynote 6 does export as PDF- you could open that up in illustrator